# Jitsi getting error in console - Error: Focus error, retry after

Tags: jitsi

I am using jitsi for the first time. 
I used [this](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/quick-install.md) repository to install it.
But it is not working fine. I am not able to connect two clients through this.
In console I am getting following error

```
[JitsiMeetJS.js] <Object.getGlobalOnErrorHandler>:  UnhandledError: null Script: null Line: null Column: null StackTrace:  Error: Focus error, retry after 1000
    at o._allocateConferenceFocusError (moderator.js:388)
    at moderator.js:320
    at u.Handler.handler (app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104)
    at u.Handler.run (app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104)
    at app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
    at Object.forEachChild (app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104)
    at u.Connection._dataRecv (app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104)
    at e.Bosh._onRequestStateChange (app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:105)
r @ Logger.js:125
getGlobalOnErrorHandler @ JitsiMeetJS.js:504
window.onerror @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:87
callErrorHandler @ GlobalOnErrorHandler.js:63
o._allocateConferenceFocusError @ moderator.js:388
(anonymous) @ moderator.js:320
(anonymous) @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
run @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
(anonymous) @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
forEachChild @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
_dataRecv @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
_onRequestStateChange @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:105
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <o._allocateConferenceFocusError>:  Focus error, retry after 1000 <iq xmlns=​"jabber:​client" type=​"error" to=​"c9c1d353-8924-487a-b0f7-0e66a6d65d1d@10.207.139.88/​876e1e6b-4949-4239-aad2-66fe898c4234" from=​"focus.10.207.139.88" id=​"c8401ace-5f20-46d5-a0cd-47429ae4e929:​sendIQ">​…​</iq>​
r @ Logger.js:125
o._allocateConferenceFocusError @ moderator.js:389
(anonymous) @ moderator.js:320
(anonymous) @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
run @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
(anonymous) @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
forEachChild @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
_dataRecv @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:104
_onRequestStateChange @ app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:105
app.bundle.min.js?v=1967:44 [conference.js] <e.value>:  CONFERENCE FAILED: conference.focusDisconnected focus.10.207.139.88 1
```

Machine details.
Ubuntu : 14.06

I  am using my self signed certificate here.
My case is similar to [this](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/1145) one. But here also not a proper solution is advised. Below my current screenshot is attached.

[image]

Comment: Hey there, you might want to give this a try. 
https://github.com/matrix-org/docker-jitsi
has good instructions on how to setup & has `jicofo` which i believe is what you are missing